# How to enable a Leaflet Draw tool programatically

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I'm using the [Leaflet Draw control](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html), and would like to enable/activate a particular tool (Draw Polygon) using JavaScript, so that this tool is active when the page loads. Is this possible?

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17144318/906814 shows how to bypass the control and start drawing directly, but I'd like instead to programatically enable the existing tool since it gives easy access to additional functionality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply trigger a `"click"` event on the "Draw a polygon" toolbar button (it has a specific class "`leaflet-draw-draw-polygon`"):

```js
document.querySelector(".leaflet-draw-draw-polygon").click();
```

Demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/zaze/1/edit?html,output